# MySQL PHP: Geting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 when using NOW() in a datetime column

Tags: php, mysql

Using the SQL in the below code:

```
public function saveOrder() {
  $id = $this->getUserId();
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, '$id', '$this->basket_lines', '$this->total', NOW() )");
  return $this->db->id();  
}
```

Where the last column in the above is a `DATETIME` field, the result in the database keeps defaulting to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I have tried the column format as `timestamp` too and used:

```
ALTER TABLE  `content ` CHANGE  `date`  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

from another post but to no avail.

Can anyone spot whats wrong?

Thanks

Edit: BTW I am escaping my SQL statement from within the DB class using

```
    $this->SQL = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($SQL);
    $this->result = $this->mysqli->query($SQL);
```

Edit 2: I am now escaping pre query with

```
 $i=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $b=mysql_real_escape_string($this->basket_lines);
    $t=mysql_real_escape_string($this->total);
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, '$i', '$b', '$t', NOW() )");
```

Still not working, this all all rather odd?

Comment: database keeps defaulting to 0000-00-00 00:00:00: That means NULL in TIMESTAMP or DATE field type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the escaping concept wrong, you need to escape the data you will insert in DB, to prevent SQL injection, not the whole query!
So you should do something like:

```
$id=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($id);
$basketlines=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($this->basket_lines);
$total=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($this->total);   
$SQL="INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, '$id', '$basketlines', '$total', NOW() )");
$this->result = $this->mysqli->query($SQL);
```

I am pretty sure that all your problem is because when escaping the whole query, then query becomes malformed and not a valid SQL query anymore.

Comment: What is the output of $SQL? It could help to check. Can you insert $SQL by hand and post if it gives error (in PHPMyAdmin for example)?

Comment: Thanks to yourself and Brad, that got it.

Comment: What caused the trouble? Now I am curious ;) You are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You aren't escaping **any** data.  In all likelihood, your data is messing up the rest of your query.  It's also very likely that you are wide open to SQL injection.  At a minimum, you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), but it would be better to use [prepared queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).

Comment: thanks, my db class handles esaping via - 

$this->SQL = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($SQL);
$this->result = $this->mysqli->query($SQL);
 -
Is this still sufficiant?

Comment: @GHarping, Absolutely not.  In fact, I don't expect that to really work much at all!  You cannot escape the whole query.  You're supposed to escape the data.  Escaping data is not just some magic that makes things safe.  You escape your data to indicate to the query parser that you mean for specific characters to be data, so they aren't interpreted as SQL.  I don't know where you found that DB class, but you should throw it away and start over with PDO.

Comment: GHarping, maybe that is the root cause of your problem. As @Brad says, you have to escape all data, but not the whole query. Try without escaping to debug and check if problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I shall certianly do that from now on. Still not working however, very confusing? ----     $i=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $b=mysql_real_escape_string($this->basket_lines);
    $t=mysql_real_escape_string($this->total);
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, '$i', '$b', '$t', NOW() )");

Comment: @GHarping I posted a full answer with the piece of code you need for escaping and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is of type TIMESTAMP

try

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (null, '$id', '$this->basket_lines', '$this->total', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )");
```

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is in fact, an alias for NOW(): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the query itself.

However I would like to advise you to read these 2 links.
http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
[http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php](http://The%20way%20you%27re%20using%20mysql%20is%20a%20HUGE%20security%20risk.)
The way you're using mysql is a HUGE security risk.